# How to map sub domains to different ports of a site hosted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, subdomain, virtual-directory

I am creating a ASP .NET MVC application. I have a requirements as below. The site can have multiple sub domains www.abc.mydomain.com, www.def.mydomain.com etc. I want to map each of the sub domain to different instances of a site on different ports, where every port is mapped to different instance of the site

e.g.

```
www.abc.mydomain.com maps to www.mydomain.com:8081

www.def.mydomain.com maps to www.mydomain.com:8082
```

The web site is hosted on IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can map to more than 1000, but the only thing is your system becomes slow if you host more application. If your system becomes slow,your web application eventually becomes slow

Mainly it reduces performance, but for your question you can host any number of port in IIS